# Sketch the graph of a function

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Hello I'm currently teaching myself precalc over the summer to get ahead in my school so I'll be on this website often to aid me in questions I may have regarding the class.

I need to know how to sketch graph of a function that satisfies

- domain of $f$ is all real numbers except 1
- $f(4)=1$
- $f(2)<0$ (this is where I'm getting confused)
- $f (-5)=0$.

I know it's a basic question and I already have an idea, but I'm not confident in the way I've done it.

Comment: So what is your idea? We want to be sure you have put in sufficient effort before we give our answers. Also, are there any other requirements such as it being a rational function?

Comment: My idea was from the 2 once I'm graphing is to connect it the (4,1) but not to cross bellow the 0. Like I said I'm not confident in what I'm doing and I've been using khan Academy to aid me, but I couldn't find a solution to a problem like mine. If you can help can you give an example very similar if you wouldn't like to answer my question ? I don't mind putting in the work or else I wouldnt even have considered takeing this class over the summer! There's no other requirements I'm aware of ,but doesn't it have to be rational(in this case atleast)?

Comment: Please put some effort into formatting your post next time, it does help in getting an answer. Finding out what LaTeX is also may help a lot. Asking a question twice does not help.

Comment: There are *many* functions satisfying these conditions.

Comment: What does "domain of $f$ is all real numbers except 1" mean? That $f$ is defined for all real numbers except one number (e.g. $x = 42$)?

Comment: It means the domain must include all numbers but the number 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally I would do :

- Draw the $x$-$y$ axes in the plane (trivial).
- Put a cross on the $x$-axis at $x=1$ to denote that the function will never have a value there, on this "virtual" vertical line.
- Draw a point at $(4,1)$.
- You must remember that at $x=2$ the function will be below the $x$-axis. You can for example grey out a small vertical portion (with small width) in the upper plan above $x=2$ above the $x$-axis to denote that the function must not go through this "forbidden"-area.
- Draw a point at $(-5,0)$.
- Then you can draw any curve that goes through your points starting from $-\infty$ to $\infty$, that has no value at $x=1$ (on the virtual forbidden vertical line) and that does not cross the grey out area.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a nice example: Consider the parabola $x^2+\frac{10}{9}x-\frac{175}{9}$, this function satisfies the conditions and is defined in $1$. This causes no problem as we may simply delete the value $1$ from the domain. In fact, any polynomial satisfying the above conditions has degree at least $2$.

The conditions you listed do not uniquely define a function. The conditions only specify the function in three points, namely $-5,2$ and $4$. So define a function $f$ by $f(-5)=0, f(2)=a$ and $f(4)=1$ with $a<0$, and for any other $x$, define $f(x)\in \mathbb{R}\setminus\left\{1\right\}$ arbitrarily. Then $f$ is a function that satisfies the conditions.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to graph **the** function that satisfies these conditions?  There is no single function, there are an infinite number of such  functions.  Since the problem says "**a** function" you can graph any one of them.  The function must satisfy 
•domain of f is all real numbers except 1 
Draw, perhaps, a light pencil line vertical at x= 1
•f(4)=1
Mark a dot at (1, 4)
•f(2)<0 (this is where I'm getting confused) 
Mark **any** point (2, Y) with Y< 0.
•f(−5)=0
Mark a dot at (-5, 0)

Now draw any graph you like coming from the left (x< 0) as long as it goes through (-5, 0).

The graph must be discontinuous at x= 1 but the problem does not what kind of discontinuity.  You could, for example, draw the graph going up to $+\infty$ as it approaches x= 1, or going down to $-\infty$, or just going through x= 1 but with an "open circle" where it crosses x= 1 to indicate that the function is not defined there.  For x> 1, if you had the curve going up to $+\infty$ or down to $-\infty$, draw the curve coming down from $+\infty$ or up from $-\infty$ (it does not have to be the same as on the other side).  If you just have an open circle where it crosses x= 1, continue that curve. Now continue the curve as you please as long as it passes through the point (2, Y) for whatever Y you chose and passes through (4, 1).

Comment: Thanks for the help I appreciate it.